# How do design a IF statement for a condition to only print out a specific type of file from my directory? (Explained more in body)

Tags: c, search, directory

As of currently if you remove the IF statement `if(strncmp(strup(buff,len) + len - 4, ".txt", 4) == 0)` the code will print out all the files in my current directory and the directories inside the current directory etc. However I want to design a IF statement such that I would only print out the files that i choose, in the below example I attempted to have it only print out ".txt" but that being said I can't seem to figure out how to properly design my condition statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define sizeFileName 500
#define filesMax 5000

int main( int argc, char ** argv) {
  FILE * fp = popen( "find . -type f", "r");
  char buff[sizeFilesName];
  int nFiles = 0;
  char * files[filesMax];
  while(fgets(buff,sizeFileName,fp)) {
    int len = strlen(buff) - 1;
    if(strncmp(strup(buff,len) + len - 4, ".txt", 4) == 0){
    files[nFiles] = strndup(buff,len);
    printf("\t%s\n", files[nFiles]);
    nFiles ++;
    }
  }
  fclose(fp);
  printf("Found %d files:\n", nFiles);
  // clean up
  for(int i = 0; i < nFiles ; i ++ ) {
    free(files[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

SIDENOTE: Basically my idea is that I believe some char is holding a large path name say "folder/folder/folder/file.txt" and basically if I could to a comparison between the files ".txt" and ".txt" then therefore it would be accepted and printed into the console.

Comment: I might be wrong, but to me, you're comparing `".TXT"` against `".txt"`

Comment: It can't be because I'm sure that strncmp could have taken into consideration say ".Txt" or ".tXT", etc.

Comment: I don't know the function `strup` but would a function `strdn` be better to compare with `".txt"`?

Comment: Note: `int len = strlen(buff) - 1; ... strup(buff,len) + len - 4` is subject exploits and problems when `strlen(buff)` is less than 4.  Better to test the length.

Comment: "' sure that strncmp could have taken into consideration say ".Txt" or ".tXT"" --> this is very doubtful.  Try `".TXT"` and see what happens.

Comment: Note that the filenames include a `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not starting at the correct offset of the string.  You want to check the last 4 characters, so start at offset `strlen(buf) - 4`.

```
int len = strlen(buff);
if (strncmp(buff + len - 4, ".txt", 4) == 0) {
```

Comment: I tried yours, it does actual run now, but I feel like the condition isn't working since now it says "0 files", which I know is not true since I have quiet a couple .txt files in my directory. *UPDATE* Nvm, I added a int len = strlen(buff) -1; and that fixed it.